# How do I find out why my merge request failed in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to merge code into GitLab but I keep getting the error message:

```
Merge failed: Something went wrong during merge pre-receive hook. Please try again.
```

I have tried several times and always get this issue.

How do I find out what the actual reason is for the fail?
Is there a log in GitLab anywhere where this is outputted?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone:

The way to do this is to do the push via the command line.  That way you get the full error message.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need to consult with the owner of your git repo as the error looks like there something went wrong in a script that the pre-receive hook will run before you push the code.

Comment: I am the owner!  I am just not sure where to look for the output from whatever is going wrong.  I can dig into the hooks and their logs but shouldn't GitLab output these somewhere in a readable form?

Comment: Well, you may check that the branch to which you are going to push your code is unprotected or make sure you are set as a maintainer/developer or the both for the repo you are working on despite being the owner.

Comment: I have worked out what was wrong, thanks.  I just want to know how to easily view the reasons for a hook failing in GitLab.